# need help to re-run my main class without killing the program

Tags: java

So basically I'm trying to make a minigame only using IF statements and in a single class, and everything is working smoothly so far. My biggest issue is, the "back" prompt. I tried system.exit(0), but since it kills the program, that won't be an answer. my question is, how do you "re-run" the class? For instance, when you are in the "options" menu, how do you go back in the main menu?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        //Main Menu Prompt.

        System.out.println ("Welcome to my mini parkour game!");
        System.out.println ("Decide which trick to use, and don't mess up!");
        System.out.println ("Choose one: Play, Quit");

        Scanner bruh = new Scanner (System.in);

        String MainMenu = bruh.nextLine ();

        // Quit Prompt.

        if (MainMenu.equals ("Quit"))
        {
            System.out.println ("You have quit the game.");
            System.exit (0);
        }

        // Play Prompt.

        if (MainMenu.equals ("Play"))
        {
            System.out.println ("Proceed to level 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10");

            Scanner playgame = new Scanner (System.in);

            String LevelSelect = playgame.nextLine ();


            if (LevelSelect.equals ("1"))
            { System.out.println("You have reached this block of code!");
            }
        }

        //code block to remind that java is case sensitive.
        else {
            System.out.println("error, try picking one again. (case sensitive.)");
            return new Main();
        }


    }
}
```

I wanted the output to be at the main menu prompt even when you are from the play prompt, without killing the program.

Comment: why not put your logic in a do while?

Comment: Whatever book or tutorial you're reading will surely teach you about **loops** pretty soon. Wait for it or skip directly to that part.

Comment: Instead of `return new Main();`, you could run `main(args);`

Comment: what exactly do you want return new Main(); to do? What you seem to be doing is creating new objects without decently cleaning the already existing ones

Comment: @dan1st No. You don't use recursion as an alternate implementation of a loop. You use a loop as a loop. Recursion is for when there is pushed and popped *state,* and when there is a clearly defined boundary condition. This situation fails both tests.

Comment: It is just another possibility to do this.

Comment: @dan1st It is just another wrong possibility, for the reasons I mentioned, which your comment does not address in any way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a while loop controlled by your user input stored in a variable will do the magic. You will have to learn how to use while loops.

If you want to advance to a God-level Java programmer use enum where you define your states and then create inside while loop a state machine using switch-case.
I am too lazy to type a working code here from my phone but something like that on a high level:

```
enum State { PLAY, QUIT };
public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean runAgain=true;
        State state;
        while (runAgain) {
          //get the input from user
          //update state
          switch(state) {
            case PLAY :
              // update state
              break;
            case QUIT:
              // update STATE
              break;
            //case WHATEVERELSE...
            default:
              assert false : "never get here";
           }
        }
    }
```

It is a bit of learning and reading java specs involved, but Hey, after doing that you'll be able to program a working algorithm for .... an ELEVATOR!
Good luck!